# Can not render dynatree treeview a second time when the containing div is cleared with $.empty()

Tags: jquery, css, dynatree

I am rendering a dynatree treeview in the #TreeDiv with openTemplate function. Before I load all units for a certain template in the dynatree I empty/clear the #TreeDiv to remove the existing tree. This works for the first time.

When I try to load other units for another template in the #TreeDiv I do not see my unit data, the div is just empty. Somehow the #TreeDiv got corrupted because the code is run normally like the first time creating the unit tree. The difference is that at the 2nd time I do an .empty() there exist already a tree.

What do I wrong?

```
function openTemplate(dlg, form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',                     
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {          
                if (response.success) {
                    dlg.dialog("close");                
                   $('#TreeDiv').empty();         
                   loadUnits(response.data);                    
                }
                else {
                    // Reload the dialog with the form to show model/validation errors 
                    dlg.html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    }

 function loadUnits(data) {       
        $('#TreeDiv').dynatree({
            onActivate: function (node) {
                getTestSteps(node.data.key);
            },            
            onLazyRead: function (node) {           
                node.appendAjax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetChildrenUnits","Unit")',
                    data: {"unitId": node.data.key, "templateId": 1 }
                });
            },
            children: data
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the invocation of empty() is not complete before the loadUnits invocation.

You could wrap the empty() call in untilTimeout. Or you could encapsulate in in a try, or an if statment. IE, if empty is finished then call loadUnits

Comment: I would run it within a 'try' block or wrap it in an if statement. you can also do untilTimeout